How to find the daily active user count each months?
Input: Activity table:



user_id
session_id
activity_date
activity_type




1
1
2019-07-20
open_session


1
1
2019-07-20
scroll_down


1
1
2019-07-20
end_session


2
4
2019-07-20
open_session


2
4
2019-07-19
send_message


2
4
2019-07-19
end_session


3
2
2019-07-19
open_session


3
2
2019-07-19
send_message


3
2
2019-07-19
end_session


4
3
2019-06-25
open_session


4
3
2019-06-25
end_session


4
3
2019-06-20
open_session


4
3
2019-06-20
end_session


5
6
2019-06-03
open_session


5
6
2019-06-03
scroll_down


5
6
2019-06-03
end_session


6
8
2019-05-25
open_session


6
8
2019-05-25
send_message


6
8
2019-05-25
end_session


7
9
2019-05-10
open_session


7
9
2019-05-10
end_session


7
9
2019-04-25
open_session


7
9
2019-04-25
end_session


8
7
2019-04-20
open_session


8
7
2019-04-20
end_session



Desired output:



month
active_users




2019-07
3


2019-06
2


2019-05
2


2019-04
2



Write a solution to find the daily active user count each months. A user was active on someday if they made at least one activity on that day.
The original question is much simpler where it only requires to find the daily active user count for a period of 30 days ending 2019-07-27 inclusively and I solved it, so I upgraded it but have been struggling with it. Could you guys help me with the syntax that could group those activity_date into month?

What RDBMS do you use? You simply need a GROUP BY clause, here an example for a SQL Server DB: https://dbfiddle.uk/0TMyXygU Depending on your RDBMS, the date function to fetch the month from the entire date differs.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What does daily active user count each month? If a user is active on two different days during a month, does that count as 1 or 2?

In MySQL you could do this:
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(activity_date, '%Y-%m') AS month, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS active_users
FROM 
    activity
WHERE 
    activity_date <= '2019-07-27'
GROUP BY 
    month
ORDER BY 
    month;

